# How to set cookie information into headers using tcl http package

Tags: http, tcl

I have created some header to login into a server,
After loggin into server, i am moving one page to another page using geturl operation using this below headers, but the problem i logged out the server i am not moving into further.

I thought it was missing cookie information.

```
set headers(Accept) "text/html\;q=0.9,text/plain\;q=0.8,image/png,*/*"
set headers(Accept-Language) "en-us,en\;q=0.5"
set headers(Accept-Charset) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8\;q=0.7,*\;q=0.7"
set headers(Proxy-Authorization) "[concat \"Basic\" [base64::encode $username:$password]]"
```

I don't how to set cookie information into headers could someone explain.

Thanks
Malli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this tool [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Cookie support in Tcl is currently exceptionally primitive; I've got 95–99% of the fix in our [fossil repository](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/timeline?r=dkf-http-cookies), but that's not much help to you. But for straight handling a session cookie for login purposes, you can “guerilla hack” it.

### Sending the cookie

To send a cookie to the server, you need to send a header `Cookie: thecookiestring`. That's done by passing the `-headers` option to `http::geturl` which has a dictionary describing what to pass. We can get that from the array simply enough:

```
set headers(Cookie) $thecookiestring
set token [http::geturl $theurl -headers [array get headers]]
# ...
```

### Receiving the cookie

That's definitely the easy bit. The rather-harder part is that you also need to check for a `Set-Cookie` header in the response when you do a login action. You get that with `http::meta` and then iterate through the list with `foreach`:

```
set thecookiestring ""
set token [http::geturl $theloginurl ...]
if {[http::ncode $token] >= 400} {error ...}
foreach {name value} [http::meta $token] {
    if {$name ne "Set-Cookie"} continue
    # Strip the stuff you probably don't care about
    if {$thecookiestring ne ""} {append thecookiestring "; "}
    append thecookiestring [regsub {;.*} $value ""]
}
```

Formally, there can be many cookies and they have all sorts of complicated features. Handling them is what I was working on in that fossil branch…

I'm assuming that you don't need to be able to forget cookies, manage persistent storage, or other such complexities. (After all, they're things you probably won't need for normal login sessions.)

Comment: As for why logout is happening, that's _enormously_ dependent on the service. No way to answer without vastly more information.